# React.createElement problem with jest tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am running my tests in jest but every time I do it, it throws a **warning**, I have looked for some references but without getting any solution. something I must say is that the tests are passing, it is just annoying to see that warning every time I run them.

```js
console.error
    Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in com
ponents) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely f
orgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
 default and named imports.

       7 | const Icons: { [key: string]: JSX.Element } = {
       8 |   cards: <CreditCard />,
    >  9 |   default: <PiggyBankOutline />,
         |            ^
      10 |   investments: <BarChart />,
      11 |   loans: <DollarStack />,
      12 |   savings: <PiggyBankOutline />,

      at printWarning (../../../../../../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:220
:30)
      at error (../../../../../../node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:196:5)
      at Object.React [as createElement] (../../../../../../node_modules/react/cjs/react
.development.js:2215:7)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../../../core/src/components/functional/CollapseList/
HeadView/index.tsx:9:12)
```

This is the file that trown the error:

```js
import { Row } from 'antd';
import React from 'react';
/*
thinking that the error could be from the imports with aliases, I also try to set the relative path but the warning still appears. On the other hand these same imports are being used in other components and they don't show any problem...
*/
import { Text, Title } from 'components';
import { BarChart, CreditCard, DollarStack, PiggyBankOutline } from 'assets';
import { ICollapseHeader } from '../CollapseList.props';

const Icons: { [key: string]: JSX.Element } = {
  cards: <CreditCard />,
  default: <PiggyBankOutline />,
  investments: <BarChart />,
  loans: <DollarStack />,
  savings: <PiggyBankOutline />,
};
```

```js
// component imported in the previews code, PiggyBankOutline.tsx
import * as React from 'react';

const PiggyBankOutline = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const MemoPiggyBankOutline = React.memo(PiggyBankOutline);
export default MemoPiggyBankOutline;
```

### UPDATE 1: Assset index

```
export { default as BarChart } from './icons/general/16/BarChart';
export { default as CreditCard } from './icons/general/16/CreditCard';
export { default as DollarStack } from './icons/general/16/DollarStack';
export { default as PiggyBankOutline } from './icons/general/16/PiggyBankOutline';
```

Comment: Do you have a index.ts file inside the assets folder ? . If yes can you add that code as well ?

Comment: @Shyam done, I update my question with the asset index